# Passing an array to function a looping through it in C

Tags: arrays, c, loops

I know I'm asking pretty basic question here, but could anyone give me a hint how to properly loop through an array which is initialized in another function ? I tried googling, found tons of videos but I didn't manage to get it right just yet. Would anyone please help me find out, what I'm missing in my code ? I'm a struggling beginner. Thanks in advance for your time.

My code (not functioning):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARR_RANGE 1000000
#define GREATEST_NUMBER 1000000

void sieve(int eratosthenes[]);

int main() 
{
    int eratosthenes[ARR_RANGE];

    int n = 999;
    int c;
    for(i = 2; i <= arrLen; ++i)
    {
        if(eratosthenes[i]!= -1)
        {
            int c = 0;
            while(n % i == 0)
            {
                n /= i;
                ++c;
            }

            if(c >= 2)
            {
                printf("%d^%d x ", i, c);
            }
            else if(c == 1)
            {
                printf("%d x ", i);
            }
        }
        else
        continue;
    }
    return 0;
}

void sieve(int eratosthenes[])
{
    for(int i = 1; i < GREATEST_NUMBER; ++i)
    {
        eratosthenes[i] = i;
    }
    
    for(int i = 2; i*i < GREATEST_NUMBER; ++i)
    {
        if(eratosthenes[i] != -1)
        {
            for(int j = 2*i; j < GREATEST_NUMBER ; j += i)
                eratosthenes[j] = -1;
        }
    }
    
    int arrLen = sizeof eratosthenes / sizeof eratosthenes[0];
}
```

Comment: `arrLen` is a local variable in `sieve`.  It's pointless to initialize it there and then not use it.  This is not visible in `main`.  Furthermore, using `sizeof eratosthenes / sizeof eratosthenes[0];` in your function is a big mistake, since at that point, `eratosthenes` is a pointer, not an array.  So this does not give what you expect.  Why don't you just use `GREATEST_NUMBER` in your main function?  Or `ARR_RANGE`.  And use `<` not `<=` or you'll shoot off the end of it.  On this note, you should only use _one_ size for the array.  It's a bug waiting to happen if you have two.

Comment: Read the code carefully. You've some declarative problems like in main() function like - you didn't declare the variable "i" in for loop. Even didn't declare arrLen.

Comment: Please take some time to read the [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There are multiple problems in your code. Also show the first few lines of the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `main` is not visible the call of function `sieve`,so the array is not passed into function, to do this you have to write in the `main` `sieve(eratosthenes);` (Passage by reference)